# Google Coral Dev Board- Setting Thermal Trip Point- Fan won't spin up

Tags: google-coral

Just set up my Google Coral Dev Board, the install of Mendel was a little rough, but now that I've flashed the board the fan won't spin up even after several reboots.

The heatsink is getting super hot. I'm a noob, any code to fix this and if so, please give me details on how to run said code?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why people down voted this question. To answer you promptly:
Current threshold is set to 65 C I believe. As soon as board reaches this temperature, the fan will turn on automatically. The commands below will disable thermal management and turn on the fan continuously:

```
echo "disabled" > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/mode
echo 8600 > /sys/devices/platform/gpio_fan/hwmon/hwmon0/fan1_target
```

To get a reading of the boards temperature please use this command below. Please keep in mind that the output measurement is in 1/1000 of degrees celsius.

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the fan temperature trip point to a lower value, like 50C.   You can change the trip point with the following command:

```
echo "50000" > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_4_temp
```

The current trip point is set at 65000, or 65C.  Since the fan is running at full speed and is a little loud for my ears.

I decided to unplug the fan and place two wires into the fan connector and power the fan directly from the 40 pin gpio header.   So I then use pin 6 to the black fan wire (ground), and pin 1 to the red fan wire (3.3 volts).  Now the fan is running quietly, and constantly, and the best part is it still keeps the Coral dev board cool.